# Count the size of only active Webelement

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

first post here.

I want the count of rows of  table which has same "id" and "class" **for a row** as another table which is inactive and is on another div.

```
<tr id="trAccountDetails" class="animate ng-scope" ng-repeat="row in displayedActiveCollection" style="">
```

I have tried doing the following but it returns the total row count of both the active and inactive table.

```
int rowCount = driver.findElements(By.id("trAccountDetails")).size();
```

Is  there a way to count the row of only the active table?

EDIT: I have tried the following code but it only returns the count as 1

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@st-table='displayedTermedCollection']/tbody/tr")).size();
```

Comment: Do the container divs have any attribute that are different for the active and inactive tables which you can use in css or xpath? You can even try a css on tr with the ng-repeat attribute (has the word 'active' in it maybe that diffrenciates) - "tr[ng-repeat='row in displayedActiveCollection'][id='trAccountDetails']"

Comment: Try using xpath or css to locate the div first and then table rows in that div. It will allow you to be bound in the div ( table containing div ) and will not search in another DIV. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate more than one property, with the xpath:

```
int rowCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='trAccountDetails' and (contains(@class,'animate'))]")).size();
```

Comment: Tried this but still returns the total row count. Thanks.

Comment: I used the class property as example. Maybe your elements are visible for other property.

Comment: `int rowCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@st-safe-src='ActiveCollection']//*[@id=\"trAccountDetails\"]")).size();`

This solved the issue. I used the "st-safe-src" property to define the active table. Thanks.